# Call blockchain.info API with javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bitcoin, blockchain

**Is it possible to call the blockchain.info API with javascript or jQuery?**

I'm trying to get all the address info in json format with:

```
https://blockchain.info/address/1Nkmns4Pan2hknkQFfRCLnoKdR5VEP324J?format=json
```

Or:

```
https://blockchain.info/address/1Nkmns4Pan2hknkQFfRCLnoKdR5VEP324J?format=json&cors=true
```

From what i've read, it should be possible, but i'm starting to doubt it now. I know I can use a PHP script, a proxy, or some kind of YQL hack, but that won't really do what I want.

Basically, i've been trying various different versions of this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Blockchain.info API</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $.getJSON( "https://blockchain.info/address/1Nkmns4Pan2hknkQFfRCLnoKdR5VEP324J?format=json&cors=true", function( data ) {
            $.each(txs.hash, function(key, value){
                $('#test').append(key+': '+value+'<br>');
            });
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="test"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But so far, nothing's worked. Am I wasting my time here?

Comment: @NotSoSmart apparently despite "cors=true" parameter - request is rejected (you see the error in the console) I suggest contacting them about the issue

Comment: Incase someone else is looking for this: I couldn't get this to work client side like I wanted, but I found that biteasy.com's RESTful API works perfectly. Great alternative.

Comment: biteasy.com is down. What are the other alternatives?

Comment: Incase some one is looking again.
I have used [Block Cypher](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/) with [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for what I want to acheive.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend to get all details at once. That would be confusing because there's so much data on the JSON data. You can fetch every data from Blockchain's Query API's with AJAX.
For example, for getting a balance of a wallet, you can do:

```
  $.ajax({url: "https://api.blockchain.com/q/addressbalance/bitcoinaddress", success: function(result){
   $("#test").html(result);
  }});
```

Hope this helps.